# Get multiple user inputs in one form field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a form field that asks the user which countries it has visited, and limit this to 10. So the user has to give ten inputs in one form field.

But when I click on the submit button it won't let the user enter a second time. It just calls the function that displays the first country that the user has entered.

How do I keep the values the user is entering in the form field and when the user has entered all the ten countries, then click on submit to call the function that would display all the countries?

```js
function validateForm() {
  var repeat = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["countries"].value;


    repeat.push(x);
  }
  document.write(repeat);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  Enter the countries:
  <input type="text" id="countries"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="validateForm()" value="Click Me!">
```

It keeps on displaying that one country the user has entered 10 times, instead of letting user enter ten countries and then displaying then when clicking on submit.

Comment: Well, you'll need 10 input elements if you want to capture 10 different inputs...

Comment: I know but isn't there a way to do that all using one form field?

Comment: Some things to consider: how do you want the user to change an incorrect entry? How does the user remove an unwanted entry? The simplest solution is to user a delimiter such as a comma and split your data server side on that. The user then needs to be informed of what to use as a delimiter. More elegant is to use dynamically added elements for each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global array for the countries and store until ten countries in the array.

```js
function enterCountry() {
    var input = document.getElementById('country');
    if (input.value && countries.length < 10) {
        countries.push(input.value);
        input.value = '';
        input.placeholder = 'insert ' + (10 - countries.length);
    }
    if (countries.length === 10) {
        input.placeholder = 'ready';
        document.getElementById('allCountries').innerHTML = countries.join(', ');
    }
}
var countries = [];
```

```html
<form id="form1">
Enter the countries:
<input type="text" id="country" placeholder="insert 10"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="enterCountry()" value="Click Me!">
</form>
<div id="allCountries"></div>
```

Comment: My question here is how does the page lets the user enter more values because when I tried it, it would let me enter one value and then refresh itself and when I entered again, it treated it like first entry. So it never let me enter 10 values.

Comment: I got it alright. It was a blunder of me not declaring button input properly.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you sketched out. I don't think it's a very good way of asking a user for 10 items, as there's no feedback as to how many they've entered, nor the ability to edit the items once entered, nor a way of clearing the list to enter 10 more. Also, this will never actually submit the list. But this meets the requirements as stated:

```js
var repeat = [];

function validateForm() {
  var countries = document.getElementById("countries");
  if (repeat.length < 10) {
    var x = countries.value;
    repeat.push(x);
    countries.value = "";
    countries.focus();
  }
  if (repeat.length === 10) {
    var hid = document.getElementById("list");
    hid.value = repeat.join('|');
    console.log(hid.value);
    var ul = document.getElementById("display");
    ul.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ul.innerHTML += `<li>${repeat[i]}</li>`;
    }
    document.getElementById("done").style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", validateForm);
};
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  Enter the countries:
  <input type="text" id="countries"><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="click" value="Click Me!">
  <input type="hidden" id="list" name="listOfCountries">
</form>
<br>
<div id="done" style="display:none">
  Countries entered:
  <ul id="display"></ul>
</div>
```

Note that the hidden fields `listOfCountries` will contain the list of 10 countries, delimited by a pipe symbol "`|`". It's up to you to post that to a server.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to make. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can get multiple input value on submit with jquery

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery, but I'll give it a try